# how to merge two arrays according to their respective key?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

how to combine two arrays within their respective keys
i tryied array_merge but it did not work as I want. I also tried with array_merge_recursive... the same...

these are my two arrays:

array 1 :

```
   array(2) {
  [264]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "64"
      ["concepto"]=>
      string(27) "IIBB Contribuyentes Locales"
      ["impuesto"]=>
      string(10) "Anticipo10"
      ["agencia"]=>
      string(4) "ARBA"
      ["vencimiento_del_mes"]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-21"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "74"
      ["concepto"]=>
      string(26) "IIBB convenio multilateral"
      ["impuesto"]=>
      string(10) "Anticipo10"
      ["agencia"]=>
      string(4) "ARBA"
      ["vencimiento_del_mes"]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-13"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["concepto"]=>
      string(11) "recaudacion"
      ["impuesto"]=>
      string(4) "IIBB"
      ["agencia"]=>
      string(4) "AGIP"
      ["vencimiento_del_mes"]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-07"
    }
  }
  [265]=>
  array(14) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(2) "65"
      ["concepto"]=>
      string(27) "IIBB Contribuyentes Locales"
      ["impuesto"]=>
      string(10) "Anticipo10"
      ["agencia"]=>
      string(4) "ARBA"
      ["vencimiento_del_mes"]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-22"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(3) "101"
      ["concepto"]=>
      string(41) "Regimen General de Percepcion (Percibido)"
      ["impuesto"]=>
      string(24) "Segunda Quincena Octubre"
      ["agencia"]=>
      string(4) "ARBA"
      ["vencimiento_del_mes"]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-13"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(3) "101"
      ["concepto"]=>
      string(41) "Regimen General de Percepcion (Percibido)"
      ["impuesto"]=>
      string(26) "Primera Quincena Noviembre"
      ["agencia"]=>
      string(4) "ARBA"
      ["vencimiento_del_mes"]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-24"
    }
  }
}
```

array 2:

```
  array(2) {
  [264]=>
  array(9) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["idImpuesto"]=>
      int(10)
      ["idConcepto"]=>
      int(19)
      ["periodo"]=>
      string(4) "2017"
      ["tipoOperacion"]=>
      string(12) "PRESENTACION"
      ["vencimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-13"
      ["formularios"]=>
      string(3) "713"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(5) {
      ["idImpuesto"]=>
      int(10)
      ["idConcepto"]=>
      int(19)
      ["periodo"]=>
      string(4) "2017"
      ["tipoOperacion"]=>
      string(4) "PAGO"
      ["vencimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-13"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(6) {
      ["idImpuesto"]=>
      int(30)
      ["idConcepto"]=>
      int(19)
      ["periodo"]=>
      string(7) "2017-10"
      ["tipoOperacion"]=>
      string(12) "PRESENTACION"
      ["vencimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-21"
      ["formularios"]=>
      string(8) "731,2002"
    }
  }
  [265]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["idImpuesto"]=>
      int(30)
      ["idConcepto"]=>
      int(19)
      ["periodo"]=>
      string(7) "2017-10"
      ["tipoOperacion"]=>
      string(12) "PRESENTACION"
      ["vencimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-22"
      ["formularios"]=>
      string(8) "731,2002"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(5) {
      ["idImpuesto"]=>
      int(30)
      ["idConcepto"]=>
      int(19)
      ["periodo"]=>
      string(7) "2017-10"
      ["tipoOperacion"]=>
      string(4) "PAGO"
      ["vencimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-22"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(5) {
      ["idImpuesto"]=>
      int(308)
      ["idConcepto"]=>
      int(19)
      ["periodo"]=>
      string(7) "2017-10"
      ["tipoOperacion"]=>
      string(4) "PAGO"
      ["vencimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2017-11-06"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

I'm not very good at explaining why I decided to graph:

[image]

If you need something else please ask me!

Comment: You really should provide the desired output in array format. The image is not really revealing how you want the merge to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution could work:

```
/*Let $array1 and $array2 be the two arrays to be combined into one $array3 */  

/* First get the unique values for the keys to be combined: */
$arr = [];
foreach($array1 as $k => $v){ $arr[] = $k; }
foreach($array2 as $k => $v){ $arr[] = $k; }
$arr = array_unique($arr);

/* Scan the two arrays with the unique keys to get the required $array3: */
$array3 = [];
foreach($arr as $v){
if(array_key_exists($v, $array1)){ $array3[$v][] = $array1[$v]; }
if(array_key_exists($v, $array2)){ $array3[$v][] = $array2[$v]; }
}

var_export($array3);   /* the desired result */
```

Sample data:

```
$array1 = array ( 264 => array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => '64', 'concepto' => 'IIBB Contribuyentes Locales', 'impuesto' => 'Anticipo10', 'agencia' => 'ARBA', 'vencimiento_del_mes' => '2017-11-21', ), 1 => array ( 'id' => '74', 'concepto' => 'IIBB convenio multilateral', 'impuesto' => 'Anticipo10', 'agencia' => 'ARBA', 'vencimiento_del_mes' => '2017-11-13', ), 2 => array ( 'id' => '1', 'concepto' => 'recaudacion', 'impuesto' => 'IIBB', 'agencia' => 'AGIP', 'vencimiento_del_mes' => '2017-11-07', ), ), 265 => array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => '65', 'concepto' => 'IIBB Contribuyentes Locales', 'impuesto' => 'Anticipo10', 'agencia' => 'ARBA', 'vencimiento_del_mes' => '2017-11-22', ), 1 => array ( 'id' => '101', 'concepto' => 'Regimen General de Percepcion (Percibido)', 'impuesto' => 'Segunda Quincena Octubre', 'agencia' => 'ARBA', 'vencimiento_del_mes' => '2017-11-13', ), 2 => array ( 'id' => '101', 'concepto' => 'Regimen General de Percepcion (Percibido)', 'impuesto' => 'Primera Quincena Noviembre', 'agencia' => 'ARBA', 'vencimiento_del_mes' => '2017-11-24', ), ), ); 

$array2 = array (264 => array ( 0 => array ( 'idImpuesto' => 10, 'idConcepto' => 19, 'periodo' => '2017', 'tipoOperacion' => 'PRESENTACION', 'vencimiento' => '2017-11-13', 'formularios' => '713', ), 1 => array ( 'idImpuesto' => 10, 'idConcepto' => 19, 'periodo' => '2017', 'tipoOperacion' => 'PAGO', 'vencimiento' => '2017-11-13', ), 2 => array ( 'idImpuesto' => 30, 'idConcepto' => 19, 'periodo' => '2017-10', 'tipoOperacion' => 'PRESENTACION', 'vencimiento' => '2017-11-21', 'formularios' => '731,2002', ), ), 265 => array ( 0 => array ( 'idImpuesto' => 30, 'idConcepto' => 19, 'periodo' => '2017-10', 'tipoOperacion' => 'PRESENTACION', 'vencimiento' => '2017-11-22', 'formularios' => '731,2002', ), 1 => array ( 'idImpuesto' => 30, 'idConcepto' => 19, 'periodo' => '2017-10', 'tipoOperacion' => 'PAGO', 'vencimiento' => '2017-11-22', ), 2 => array ( 'idImpuesto' => 308, 'idConcepto' => 19, 'periodo' => '2017-10', 'tipoOperacion' => 'PAGO', 'vencimiento' => '2017-11-06', ), ), );

Result:
$array3 = array ( 264 => array ( 0 => array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => '64', 'concepto' => 'IIBB Contribuyentes Locales', 'impuesto' => 'Anticipo10', 'agencia' => 'ARBA', 'vencimiento_del_mes' => '2017-11-21', ), 1 => array ( 'id' => '74', 'concepto' => 'IIBB convenio multilateral', 'impuesto' => 'Anticipo10', 'agencia' => 'ARBA', 'vencimiento_del_mes' => '2017-11-13', ), 2 => array ( 'id' => '1', 'concepto' => 'recaudacion', 'impuesto' => 'IIBB', 'agencia' => 'AGIP', 'vencimiento_del_mes' => '2017-11-07', ), ), 1 => array ( 0 => array ( 'idImpuesto' => 10, 'idConcepto' => 19, 'periodo' => '2017', 'tipoOperacion' => 'PRESENTACION', 'vencimiento' => '2017-11-13', 'formularios' => '713', ), 1 => array ( 'idImpuesto' => 10, 'idConcepto' => 19, 'periodo' => '2017', 'tipoOperacion' => 'PAGO', 'vencimiento' => '2017-11-13', ), 2 => array ( 'idImpuesto' => 30, 'idConcepto' => 19, 'periodo' => '2017-10', 'tipoOperacion' => 'PRESENTACION', 'vencimiento' => '2017-11-21', 'formularios' => '731,2002', ), ), ), 265 => array ( 0 => array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => '65', 'concepto' => 'IIBB Contribuyentes Locales', 'impuesto' => 'Anticipo10', 'agencia' => 'ARBA', 'vencimiento_del_mes' => '2017-11-22', ), 1 => array ( 'id' => '101', 'concepto' => 'Regimen General de Percepcion (Percibido)', 'impuesto' => 'Segunda Quincena Octubre', 'agencia' => 'ARBA', 'vencimiento_del_mes' => '2017-11-13', ), 2 => array ( 'id' => '101', 'concepto' => 'Regimen General de Percepcion (Percibido)', 'impuesto' => 'Primera Quincena Noviembre', 'agencia' => 'ARBA', 'vencimiento_del_mes' => '2017-11-24', ), ), 1 => array ( 0 => array ( 'idImpuesto' => 30, 'idConcepto' => 19, 'periodo' => '2017-10', 'tipoOperacion' => 'PRESENTACION', 'vencimiento' => '2017-11-22', 'formularios' => '731,2002', ), 1 => array ( 'idImpuesto' => 30, 'idConcepto' => 19, 'periodo' => '2017-10', 'tipoOperacion' => 'PAGO', 'vencimiento' => '2017-11-22', ), 2 => array ( 'idImpuesto' => 308, 'idConcepto' => 19, 'periodo' => '2017-10', 'tipoOperacion' => 'PAGO', 'vencimiento' => '2017-11-06', ), ), ), )
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing with `array_merge` is that it will treat numerical keys differently from non-numerical keys. The `+` operator will not treat them differently, but takes the value from the first array when both have the same key.

So neither does what you want.

You could use this function, which will work like `array_merge_recursive`, but will not treat numerical keys differently:

```
function mergeByKeys($a, $b) {
    if (!is_array($a) || !is_array($b)) return $a;
    foreach (array_flip(array_keys($a))+array_flip(array_keys($b)) as $key => $_) {
        $results[$key] = !isset($a[$key]) ? $b[$key]
                       : (!isset($b[$key]) ? $a[$key] 
                          : mergeByKeys($a[$key], $b[$key]));
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: Very interesting solution, however I got different results with the sample data in my answer here. I wonder what might be the issue causing this.

Comment: Yes, I had put a comments note on the solution on how to get the two arrays for the sample data.

Comment: Thanks for the `var_export` suggestion. But I have been referring to my answer here at @John B. Walugembe, trying to compare results. I have removed the Note comment and instead edited the sample data there using the `var_export`  to show the arrays more clearly. The difference I am querying can be seen from this link: http://algowriter.com/john/test_arr_merge.php

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you from the start. The reason our results are different, is that my solution is recursive, and you instead append the individual subarrays into the result. The OP is not clear in what they want, so either might be what they want as output, or still something else.